# Creating 60k+ pages slows down page performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I work on a fairly large e-commerce site that was built using gatsby. Up till now we have been dynamically loading all our product data at runtime so we only had 1 product page for the whole site and a total of about 3k pages.

However, for SEO reason we are trying to statically build all our product pages and that adds about 60k pages to the website.

After we did this our app.[hash].js file has increased to 10mb and general page performance as tanked. Hovering links causes page to hang for a half a second.

We are creating the product pages by passing the product data as page context when calling create pages:

```
  const productsRaw = await fetch(productsUrl)
  const products = await productsRaw.json()

  /* Build a page for each product */
  if (products) {
    products.forEach(product => {
      const productPage = {
        path: `/product${product.route}`,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/product.jsx`),
        context: product,
      }
      createPage(productPage)
    })
  }
```

We believe the bad page performance is related to the app.js file jumping to about 10mb. Is there any optimization we can make to reduce the size of this file or is this just unavoidable when increasing the page count?

*Update*

After analyzing the webpack I found that the issue is that each product page is added to the match-path.json file. This caused the file to exceed 10mb. Is it necessary that all these paths get added to the file and if not is there a way to correct that when I create the page?

[image]

*Update 2*

I ended up writing a script to remove all non-regex paths from match-path.json before webpack runs and the site seems to work great and perform very well. Any way I can prevent them from getting added in the first place?

Comment: How does building things statically improve SEO? It really doesn't matter.

Comment: And another question, how is building pages related to page performance? You build all products statically for each page view?

Comment: @RoboRobok https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/seo/. Gatsby is SEO friendly because, among other things, being a static site generator improves the Google Insights punctuation dramatically (high-speed delivery performance and minimum API/third-party request).

Comment: 1. In our case, google bot is not properly crawling these pages because product data is loaded in after page load is complete.
2. No we build product pages once per build not per view and store files in a bucket. I'm still trying to figure out why this is affecting page perfomance but i belive it has something to do with how gatsby is mapping the files for each page. I think adding 60k pages to that map is increasing CPU usage on the site.

Comment: @FerranBuireu server-side rendering doesn't mean static generation. It means that the content is available in the page source. It still can be 100% dynamically generated.

Comment: I know, I work daily with Gatsby, what I mean is that you provide always data to the user because it's already built so, it improves Insight's performance. When you build and compile your assets you retrieve all the data and create the pages, that's where @user1449109 has the issue. The data is dynamic but your are serving it statically, does not stop you to make an API request and ask for new data once the page is generated, but it is a low %.

What I would suggest is to create an S3 bucket with great CPU performance to build your site and destroy it once it's done.

Comment: @FerranBuireu I'm a bit confused about what you're suggesting. We do use big powerful machines to do the build and the builds are not the fastest but we are ok with that. The actual issue is on the client-side. The page performance for the user is really bad when navigating the page. Fetching page-data.json by hovering a link seems to eat up alot of client CPU and makes page hange for a split second and the app.js file has grown from .5mb to 10mb. I'm not sure if there are optimzation I could look into or if this is just the reality of gatsby with 60k+ pages.

Comment: @JoshStarrett I misunderstood your issue then. I thought you were having trouble with build time.

Answer (score 1):

While 60k is a fair number of pages to generate at build-time, it's not extreme. The issue you're having is that you are passing product data in via context. That is intended to be a small amount of data that allows you to query for the data in your page template.

1. In `gatsby-node.js`, call `createPage` for each page that should be exported
2. Include the minimum amount of information needed to find the data for that page in the `context` passed to `createPage` (e.g. an ID or slug)
3. In your page template, use the context to filter the data returned by the GraphQL query (each property of `context` is available as an argument to a named GraphQL query)
4. Fetch only the data you need for the page in your GraphQL query; any data that remains constant across all instances of the component can use a static query instead

If you follow the above, each page query data will be written out as an individual page-data.json file that will be rather small (it's literally just the query data). That should be the only data that is prefetched when you hover over a link.

Note: if, after doing this, your `app.<hash>.js` file is still large, chances are you have some data you're not expecting in there. Check it out using [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to see where the weight is coming from.

Comment: Thanks man, so I ran the analyzer and it looks like our problem is that each product page is added to the match-path.json file. That file has grown to be very large and its the reason our app.js file is so large. I will edit my original question above to include screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. So we actually do create another dynamic product page that contains a matchPath. This page is used just in case we dont properly build out all the products and a user tries to access a product thats not statically generated. In this case, it would hit a match path that would dynamically load product data. This page also uses the same template as the other product page. When I remove this page from getting created all the other products get removed from match-path.json but when it is included all the other products get added to the match-path.json. Here is the code:

```
/* Build a page for each product */
  if (products) {
    products.forEach(product => {
      const productPage = {
        path: `/product${product.route}`,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/product.jsx`),
        context: { product, banners: PDPBannerData ? PDPBannerData.contentfulProductAdditionalContent : null },
      }
      createPage(productPage)
    })
  }

  const productPage = {
    path: '/product',
    component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/product.jsx`),
    context: { banners: PDPBannerData ? PDPBannerData.contentfulProductAdditionalContent : null },
    matchPath: `/furniture/product/*`,
  }
  createPage(productPage)
```

I'm assuming it does this for a reason, any thoughts on why this is necessary? We were talking about removing this dynamic page so its probably not a big deal for us to just deleted it and move on.